# Secure iOS to online database connection

Tags: mysql, ios, security

I have an iPhone application that needs to collect data from an online MySQL database. I've written a PHP web service so I collect the data with JSON. The problem is that everyone can see the data if they go to the URL now. How do i secure the data transfer properly?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: How about using POST as the method of data transfer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, if you are showing data private to a particular user, then each user will generally have an account (user id and password). The app will pass the user's credentials to the server before the server will provide the user's data.

You can also do something similar using SSO integration, or OAuth (ala Facebook).

In some cases, your app may only pass the username/password on the initial call and receive a session ID, which the app passes on remaining calls. This allows the server to store session data.

Even if the data isn't private to a particular user, you can use accounts to restrict access and privileges for a publicly reachable web API.

In all of the above cases encryption such as SSL (HTTPS) must be used to protect the authentication mechanisms and data transfer.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will use a post request to send the login data to the server over an https connection and then make a single sign on session as you suggested. I also will check the submitted login data to prevent from sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your data is public for all users of your app, in other words, you don't want to implement a login mechanism for your users. If you just want to make sure you return the data only to users of your app and not to anyone who happens to enter the right URL in their browser, you will need to sign your requests, so that only requests from your app are accepted by your server.

I use a secret key that my app uses to create a hash/digest of the request which the server verifies (it knows the secret key as well). Also I make sure requests cannot be replayed if they are intercepted by adding a timestamp and a nonce. The timestamp is checked to be within 10 minutes of the server's timestamp (relaxed sync) and the nonce must be unique (server keeps the last 10 minutes of nonces). This way no-one can copy the same request, the server will just serve an error if they try.

This post explains how to sign your requests in a bit more detail:
http://www.naildrivin5.com/blog/2008/04/21/rest-security-signing-requests-with-secret-key-but-does-it-work.html